# Is it possible to have 2 controllers with the same name and in different packages, grails 2.1.3

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.1

I want to create 2 controllers with the same name and in different packages, one for UI the other is REST.

Is this possible in grails 2.1.3? if yes, how?

ps: I tried and it didn't work, grails mix both controllers

Answer (score 0):

Defining and mapping controllers to URLs is done by convention.  So if
you have the same name `XController` in different packages, that would
lead to the same mapping - and how would you decide which
controller/action to call if both just have the same?

Rename one of your controller so it makes sense for the developer (e.G.
`UiXController`) and then optionally do an [url
mapping](https://guides.grails.org/grails_url_mappings/guide/index.html#urlMappings)
if the URLs are important for some reason.

Comment: FYI... The above is correct in Grails 2.1.3.  If you upgrade to 2.3 or later, you can use the `namespace` property in the controllers to disambiguate them.